# Agents in Pedestrian weird behavior

Tags: anylogic

I am building a model where i should be telling agents to wait in set of couches using the Pedestrian library , but once agents reaches the couches node they keep moving back and fourth although attractors used ?
what should happen is to sit and stay stable
what seems to be the problem here  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once faced the same issue and reached out to AnyLogic support. Pedestrian movement is controlled by algorithms which can cause this. These algorithms are impacted by the diameter you pick for the pedestrians and their comfortable speed. You can change those to 0 for example once they are on the couches. But then you need to change that again to the original speed after they exit the couches. Here is the email I received to my initial question:

> Yes, it is common for pedestrians to shake a little bit in a wait block. This is a side effect of the algorithm that makes pedestrians stay away from obstacles and other pedestrians. Smaller diamiter reduces the impact of the obstavles on the pedestrians. But it is better to change the comfortable speed to 0. Then, they will stand still.

Here is how I've done it:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Emile , i used the two PedEnter blocks , one PedEnter block to change the Comfortable speed to zero value and another to get it back to it's initial value in this case pedestrians once they sit on the couch they are not leaving it

Comment: I added a screenshot to my answer. I changed the speed from within the wait block itself.

Answer (score -1):

Pedestrians cannot "sit still". As soon as they sense someone else close by, they "get nervous", based on how their collision avoidance is working internally.

If you have to freeze them, one way would be to convert them to normal agents once they arrive at their destination (and re-convert into Peds once they need moving).

Check the help as convert agents into different types is a useful skill that is applied a lot normally. Also saves you performance (no need to do Ped stuff to agents that just sit around)

Comment: how i can convert agent types  ?

Comment: Hi @LaRoiZi happy to help. But please ask new questions in new issues, this is how SOF works best :) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow